# Jar containing AutoBeanFactoryMagic

Tags: gwt, autobean

What is the jar that I should include to use this package:

```
import com.google.gwt.autobean.server;
```

I try to use the following class on the servlet:

> AutoBeanFactoryMagic

I use GWT 2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its now called `AutoBeanFactorySource` in the `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm` package, within the `requestfactory-server.jar`, `requestfactory-client.jar`, `gwt-user.jar` and `gwt-servlet.jar` (we're working on modularization to avoid such duplication).

Answer (score 1):

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/autobean/server/AutoBeanFactoryMagic.html

Note the note: AutoBeans has moved to com.google.web.bindery.autobeans. This package will be removed in a future version of GWT.

Probably you are searching for the wrong thing....